# How to call Sencha Touch code from a phonegap function?

Tags: cordova, extjs, touch

I'm using Phonegap 2.2 and Sencha Touch 2.0.

I'd like to call Sencha Touch specific function from within a Phonegap pause event, code like so:

```
document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
function onPause() {
    //sencha function here, get Ext.Viewport.getItems()
}
```

This currently doesn't work, as it thinks Ext is undefined. How do I get a reference to my Ext application so I can manipulate my Sencha code through Phonegap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that you have not initialized Sencha Touch before the device ready function has been called. Ext.Viewport will work as long as Sencha Touch has been initialized.

Comment: Nothing better than the simple ones ;-)